# How to use XPath in CasperJS' evaluate function

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

We can use `document.querySelector` in the `casper.evaluate` function. But I could not find any documentation illustrating the use of XPath selectors inside the evaluate function. Is it possible to do the same? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all browsers support XPath through [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript). PhantomJS does so too (XPath 1.0).

CasperJS provides some convenience functions to use it. In the page context (inside `casper.evaluate()`) there are the two functions [`__utils__.getElementByXPath(expression [, scope])`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getelementbyxpath) and [`__utils__.getElementsByXPath(expression [, scope])`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getelementsbyxpath).

This example prints the href of the first `<a>` element it finds that has a `href` attribute:

```
casper.echo(casper.evaluate(function(){
    return __utils__.getElementByXPath("//a[@href]").href
}));
```

CasperJS also supports XPath expressions outside of the page context with a helper function:

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
```

which enables *most* CasperJS functions to use XPath expressions instead of CSS selectors:

```
casper.echo(casper.getElementAttribute(x("//a[@href]"), "href"));
```

<sup>This is similar, but not the same as the example above, because of the differences between element properties and attributes.</sup>